# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setBackground(Color) from the type Component

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting this error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setBackground(Color) from the type Component with this piece of code;

```
    public class ColourChoice {
        private static JPanel myContentPane = new JPanel();
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            Object[] colourchoice = {"Default", "Orange"};   
            String UserInput = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a colour","ColourChoice",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,colourchoice, "Default");
             if (UserInput.equals("Orange")) myContentPane.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setSize(100, 100);
            JPanel myContentPane = new JPanel();
            window.setContentPane(myContentPane);

     }
  }
```

I have a JFrame, inside I have a JPanel  and with the Frame and panel load, the user can choose a colour from a dropdown menu which will appear before the actual window loads but however, when I write the code for the color 'Panel.setBackground(Color.Orange);' it is giving me the above error.

Comment: You are making static reference to the method. Create object from your panel and call setBackground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, don't use `==` to compare Strings, but instead use the `.equals(...)` method. As has been well discussed on this site, `==` checks if one object is one and the same as another object; it checks for *identity*, whereas the equals (or equalsIgnoreCase) method checks if the Strings have the same chars in the same order, which is what you're interested in.
2. Next of all, be sure that you're calling your method on a variable, on an instance, not on the class `java.AWT.Panel`. Note that variable names should begin with a lower case letter. Do this anyway to avoid confusing yourself and others.
3. The key to this exercise is getting a valid reference to the JPanel whose background color you want to change. This object should be assigned to a non-static class field so that other methods can get a handle to it and call methods on it.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your updated code, your problem is here:

```
// likely in some constructor or method
Object[] colourchoice = {"Default", "Orange"};   
String UserInput = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose a colour","ColourChoice",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,colourchoice, "Default");
if (UserInput == "Orange") Panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

GUIDesign window = new GUIDesign();
window.setVisible(true);
window.setSize(100, 100);
JPanel Panel = new JPanel();  // ***** here
window.setContentPane(Panel);
```

Problems:

- Don't name your variable "Panel". Again variable names should begin with a lower case letter.
- Since you're declaring this variable inside of a method or constructor, this means that *it is visible **only** inside the same variable or constructor.
- **Again** the variable should be declared at the **class level** as a non static variable.
- You're **still** using `==` to compare Strings after getting recommendations not to do so -- why?

e.g.,

```
public class MyGui {
  private JPanel myContentPane = new JPanel();

  MyGui() {
     // add myContentPane to the GUI
  }
```

Now you can use the myContentPane anywhere in the class.

---

**Edit 2**
For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ColorBackground {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 450;

   // my main JPanel. I declare it in the class
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         // so kleopatra doesn't down-vote me
         return ColorBackground.this.getPreferredSize();
      };
   };
   private JComboBox colorBox = new JComboBox(ColorChoices.values());

   public ColorBackground() {
      mainPanel.add(colorBox);

      colorBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ColorChoices choice = (ColorChoices) colorBox.getSelectedItem();
            mainPanel.setBackground(choice.getColor()); // now I can call methods on the field
         }
      });
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color Background");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ColorBackground().getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum ColorChoices {
   DEFAULT("Default", null), ORANGE("Orange", Color.orange), BLUE("Blue",
         Color.blue), HOT_PINK("Hot Pink", new Color(255, 64, 128));

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }

   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }

   private ColorChoices(String name, Color color) {
      this.name = name;
      this.color = color;
   }

   private String name;
   private Color color;
}
```

---

**Edit 3**
Regarding your latest code update:

- Get all that code out of the main method.
- Create a true OOP-complaint program, one with constructors, non-static fields, non-static methods.
- Study Java before studying Swing.

Comment: @CherryW: Yes all state-changing methods should be called inside of a method, or constructor, or other block of code, and not out free in the class, if that's what you're asking, but that's not the reason for your error. The reason is that you're trying to make a method call on a ***class*** not on an ***object***.

Comment: @CherryW: as I said, that's not the reason for your error. Again, you need to make the method call on a variable that references an object, not on the class.

Comment: @CherryW: Again, by calling the method `setBackground(...)` on an object. You need first to get a reference to whatever it is you're trying to set the background of, and we can't help you with the limited bit of information you've shared so far. If you need more help, please show us more information, especially how we can get a reference to the JPanel that holds your GUI, that is added to your JFrame's contentPane.

Comment: @CherryW: the key is getting a valid reference to the JPanel whose background color you want to change. This object should be assigned to a non-static class field so that other methods can get a handle to it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pasted the full code, the code which I pasted previously is in the main class, if that makes any difference to how the program should be run.

Comment: and also sorry I forgot to change the == sign

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I did what you said and now I get no errors, however it also does not change the colour of the contentpane.

Comment: @CherryW: You're asking us to guess why code you've not shown us is not working, but unfortunately, only Jon Skeet has this ability. I've posted an example program of what I am getting at. If you still need our help, then post relevant code and information.

Comment: @CherryW: I see. Regarding your latest code, get rid of the local myContentPane variable. Declare and initialize it in the class, and don't re-declare and initialize it in the main method.

Comment: @CherryW: but seriously let's get away from toy programs that are little more than main method programs. You should focus on creating OOP-compliant classes, creating objects from these classes and using these objects. You will want to study Java OOP basics as these are fundamental concepts that are absolutely necessary for creating Swing GUI's or pretty much any Java program.

Comment: I have started learning OOP at my collage but only had two classes on it so far, are there any books / other resources you can recommend that I can look at for extra study outside classes?

Comment: @CherryW: I have learned all my OOP and coding on my own, and have used several different books and online tutorials. Consider looking at Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" for one. Consider checking out the Head First books, including their Java book, their Design Patterns book.

Comment: Btw, thanks for all your help. Your edit 3 was sort of what I wanted but the code is one page long.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels, if possible can you help me with one more problem please.